# ¿Cómo pasar un array por $_POST?

Tags: php, array, post

Veréis estaba mirando de recuperar los datos de un `array` mediante `$_POST`. Pero siempre que lo hago me dice que el indice no esta definido. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<form action= "#" method="post"> 
    <h2>Registro</h2>
      <?php while(($resfila = mysqli_fetch_array($names)))
      { ?>
          <div class="col-25">
              <label><?php echo $resfila[1]; ?></label><br/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-75">
             <input type="text" name="<?php $resfila[0]; ?>" required><br/> 
          </div>
      }
      <button class= "button" type="submit" name="save">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

El formulario funciona ya que rellena el array con los nombres de cada columna. Pero al intentar recogerlo con el POST me dice que no esta definido.

Al hacer un `print_r($_POST);`, tampoco muestra nada `Array ( [save] => )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu error se debe a que rellenas el `<input name="` con un valor dinamico cuando este debe ser fijo. y el campo `<input value="` el que deba cambiar!
para que puedas recojer con `$_POST["nombre_del_campo_name"]`.
ahora bien si quieres que enviar un arreglo debes hacer agregarle `[]` al nombre que le asignes a `name`.

**ejemplo:**

```
//variable
<input name="nombre" value="<?php echo "dinamico"; ?>">
//arreglo
<input name="nombre[]" value="<?php echo "dinamico"; ?>">
<input name="nombre[]" value="<?php echo "dinamico2"; ?>">
<input name="nombre[]" value="<?php echo "dinamico3"; ?>">
```

y recojes este campo con: `$_POST["nombre"];`

Comment: Vale, ya comprendo, ahora consigo recoger los valores introducidos por el usuario en el formulario. Pero ¿y si lo que quiero conseguir, es el nombre de las columnas contenidas en el array `$resfila[0]`?

Comment: Debes hacer un mysqli_fetch_assoc en vez de mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: Vale! Ya funciona. Muchas gracias!